# Breadth First Search in Prolog

Tags: prolog, breadth-first-search

I'm new to Prolog and currently implementing DFS (depth-first search) and BFS (breadth-first search) algorithms. My DFS works fine as the code below, but the BFS is terminated and aborted when it reaches the leaf node (it doesn't backtrack and continue searching). 
I also read some sample code about this but there are some functions they don't define like s(Node, NewNode)... so it's hard to understand, or the version use Queue is too complicated.

Here is my code: 
Some ground functions:

```
%connected(+Start, +Goal, -Weight)
connected(1,7,1).
connected(1,8,1).
connected(1,3,1).
connected(7,4,1).
connected(7,20,1).
connected(7,17,1).
connected(8,6,1).
connected(3,9,1).
connected(3,12,1).
connected(9,19,1).
connected(4,42,1).
connected(20,28,1).
connected(17,10,1).

connected2(X,Y,D) :- connected(X,Y,D).
connected2(X,Y,D) :- connected(Y,X,D).

next_node(Current, Next, Path) :-
    connected2(Current, Next, _),
    not(member(Next, Path)).
```

DFS implement:

```
depth_first(Goal, Goal, _, [Goal]).
depth_first(Start, Goal, Visited, [Start|Path]) :-
    next_node(Start, Next_node, Visited),
    write(Visited), nl,
    depth_first(Next_node, Goal, [Next_node|Visited], Path).
```

BFS implement:

```
breadth_first(Goal, Goal, _,[Goal]).
breadth_first(Start, Goal, Visited, Path) :-
    findall(X,
            (connected2(X,Start,_),not(member(X,Visited))),
            [T|Extend]),
    write(Visited), nl,
    append(Visited, [T|Extend], Visited2),
    append(Path, [T|Extend], [Next|Path2]),
    breadth_first(Next, Goal, Visited2, Path2).
```

The *Path* is something like the Queue list.
For example when call DFS:

```
?- depth_first(1, 28, [1], P).
```

BFS:

```
?- breadth_first(1, 28, [1], []).
```

Comment: Your `breadth_first/4` predicate has an inconsistency in its implementation. Your `depth_first` is designed to instantiate the last argument with the resulting path. Your `breadth_first/4` starts out by assuming you're going to pass in `[]`, but then the base case attempts to instantiate the last argument with `[Goal]` which likely won't match whatever `Path2` is being passed to it. You just need to reset your thinking on how you want to design that predicate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, the usual notion of `s(A,B)` is just like your `connect2(A,B,_)`.

You should make your interface predicates explicit:

```erlang
depth_first( Start, Goal, Path):-
    depth_first( Start, Goal, [Start], Path).
```

Maintaining a queue in BFS is not complicated at all. Instead of `Visited`, have `VisitedLists` queue (pop from front; add at end; thus [FIFO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO_(computing_and_electronics))):

```erlang
consed( A, B, [B|A]).

bfs( Goal, [Visited|Rest], Path) :-                     % take one from front
    Visited = [Start|_],            
    Start \== Goal,
    findall( X,
        ( connected2(X, Start, _), \+ member(X, Visited) ),
        [T|Extend]),
    maplist( consed(Visited), [T|Extend], VisitedExtended),      % make many
    append( Rest, VisitedExtended, UpdatedQueue),       % put them at the end
    bfs( Goal, UpdatedQueue, Path ).
```

When the goal is reached, `Path` is instantiated:

```erlang
bfs(Goal, [[Goal|Visited]|_], Path):- 
    reverse([Goal|Visited], Path).
```

The interface call needs to be adjusted correspondingly. It should be

```erlang
breadth_first( Start, Goal, Path):- bfs( Goal, [[Start]], Path).
```

*later note:* repeated `append`ing of course causes quadratic slowdown, so for efficiency this should be re-written with difference lists (also a straightforward task).

Comment: @hardik-upadhyay thank you for your [edit suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/27737717). I used the same piece of code as was in the question, apparently, so if that was ever to be changed, the changes would have to be introduced in sync to the question as well. since many years have passed, I think it's all better left as it is. :)