# Tree Breadth-First in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I have a tree :

[image]

Whith this code :

```
/* The tree database */ 

:- op(500,xfx,'is_parent'). 

a is_parent b.    c is_parent g.     f is_parent l.     j is_parent q. 
a is_parent c.    c is_parent h.     f is_parent m.     j is_parent r. 
a is_parent d.    c is_parent i.     h is_parent n.     j is_parent s. 
b is_parent e.    d is_parent j.     i is_parent o.     m is_parent t. 
b is_parent f.    e is_parent k.     i is_parent p.
```

I would like to do a depth-first research and a breadth-first research :

[image]

For the depth-first research, I did:

```
search(A) :- write(A),
            test(A).

test(A) :- nl,
          A is_parent B,
          print(B),
          test(B).
```

**The rule works  :** a -> b -> e -> k -> f -> l -> m -> t -> c -> g -> h -> n -> i -> o -> p -> d -> j -> q -> r -> s

But I don't know how to do breadth-first research. I would like to have this outing:

a -> b -> c -> d-> e -> f -> g -> g -> h -> i -> i -> j -> k -> l -> m -> n -> o -> p -> q -> r -> s -> t

I have no leads and I don't know where to start.

Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: Should your BFS solution really have duplicates?

Comment: @ScottHunter No. Only display the values once in the tree.

Comment: So your "expected outing" is incorrect?

Comment: You might find this helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/q/34082799/535275

Comment: You should not double post questions, e.g. [SWI-Prolog forum](https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/t/tree-breadth-first-in-prolog/1541/7?u=ericgt)

Answer (score 0):

/*
The following shows an implementation of
both depth-first-search '`dfs`'
also breadth-first-search '`bfs`' .
The difference between the implementations
is minor and marked in the code .

The OP had '`print`' statements
scattered throughout the code ;
this implementation instead
produces the results as a list
which can be printed if required .

Often it is the case that such '`print`'
statements do not give desired results
because dependent upon the fine-grained
happenstance of procedural sequence .
The declarativ nature of Prolog
means that the outcome as iterativ process
is a secondary and sometimes obtuse concern .
*/

/*

```
*/

:- op(2'1,xfy,'is_parent') .

'a' is_parent 'b' .

'b' is_parent 'c' .
'b' is_parent 'd' .

'c' is_parent 'e' .
'c' is_parent 'f' .

'd' is_parent 'g' .
'd' is_parent 'h' .

/*
```

*/

/*

```
*/

child(A,B) :-
A is_parent B .

children(A,Bs) :-
setof(B,child(A,B),Bs) .

valid(A) :-
\+ \+ child(A,_) .

valid(A) :-
\+ \+ child(_,A) .

/*
```

*/

/*

```
*/

:- style_check(-discontiguous) .

dfs(A,Bs) :-
valid(A) ,
dfs(A,Bs,[A]) .

bfs(A,Bs) :-
valid(A) ,
bfs(A,Bs,[A]) .

dfs(A,[]) :-
\+ valid(A) .

bfs(A,[]) :-
\+ valid(A) .

dfs(A,[B|Bs],[B|Cs]) :-
\+ children(B,_) ,
dfs(A,Bs,Cs) .

bfs(A,[B|Bs],[B|Cs]) :-
\+ children(B,_) ,
bfs(A,Bs,Cs) .

dfs(A,[B|Bs],[B|Cs]) :-
children(B,Ds) ,
append(Ds,Cs,Es) , % different than bfs .
dfs(A,Bs,Es) .

bfs(A,[B|Bs],[B|Cs]) :-
children(B,Ds) ,
append(Cs,Ds,Es) , % different than dfs .
bfs(A,Bs,Es) .

dfs(_,[],[]) .

bfs(_,[],[]) .

/*
```

*/

/*

```
*/

:- [library(plunit)] .

:- begin_tests(dfs) .

test('1',[nondet,true(As=['a','b','c','e','f','d','g','h'])]) :-
dfs('a',As) .

test('2',[nondet,true(As=['d','g','h'])]) :-
dfs('d',As) .

test('3',[nondet,true(As=['e'])]) :-
dfs('e',As) .

test('4',[nondet,true(As=[])]) :-
dfs('bogus',As) .

:- end_tests(dfs) .

/*
```

*/

/*

```
*/

:- begin_tests(bfs) .

test('1',[nondet,true(As=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h'])]) :-
bfs('a',As) .

test('2',[nondet,true(As=['d','g','h'])]) :-
bfs('d',As) .

test('3',[nondet,true(As=['e'])]) :-
bfs('e',As) .

test('4',[nondet,true(As=[])]) :-
bfs('bogus',As) .

:- end_tests(bfs) .

/*
```

*/

/*
sample run

```
?- run_tests .
% PL-Unit: dfs .... done
% PL-Unit: bfs .... done
% All 8 tests passed
true .

?-
```

*/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help This information should help you with making your answer more obviously helpful by increasing readability. Consider writing some explaining prose instead of putting everything into comments inside the code. Just in case the explanation is in code comments because you copied this from somewhere, take care to attribute this correctly.